# Why is there a millisecond time delay between the actions of one thread and another asynchronous one?

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv, lag, scheduledexecutorservice

I've been developing some computer vision software using java open CV to aim a turret and the basic structure of the program is the following:

A parent class, the Java-FX application thread which handles the user JFX interface functions, runs the scheduled-service-executor threads discussed below, and contains an instance of a class called Turret and one called Target.

For interest sake, the turret class has a function called Aim which makes use of the java simple serial library

Two threads are scheduled by this parent application class to run and are called like so:

```
Start-processing-loops()
Runnable ImageProcessLoop = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            capture footage and process frames()
            Store data extracted from frames in Target class()
        }
});
frametimer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
frametimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(ImageProcessLoop, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Runnable DataProcessLoop = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Use data stored in Target class to call a function in Turret class()
            }
    });
datatimer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
datatimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(DataProcessLoop, 0, ImProc.frametime/2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

When calling the function Aim in the class Turret by either the camera processing thread, or by the parent FX-application class, there is zero delay in its execution.

When calling the Aim command from the data processing thread, there is a noticeable (roughly 100 ms) delay before the command is executed.

Why would the one thread, and the parent class have no delay, but the data processing thread does.

Problems that have been checked:

- Data process loop takes long time to process:
  No, the measured time for processing is 1 ms. This is also proved by the 
  fact that the data is shown in real time on screen by the parent class.
- Running the processing command on the same thread as the image processing 
  (first listed executor service) there is again no delay in when the Aim 
  command is called

Kind Regards,

Dale

Comment: Well you're wrong about a new thread being created every time. That would be immensely slow and inefficient.

Comment: That's problably too much information about the context and too few about the problem

Comment: Okay, I will try and improve the question, make it more specific. If the thread isn't created every time, what happens when the executor tries to call it again if its not done with its previous work?